# A pointer-to-member is not valid for a managed class

Tags: c++-cli

I have a Windows Form in Visual Studio C++. (CLR)

In the header file I declare `bool isRunning` (to find if notepad is running):

```
private: 
    bool isRunning(LPCSTR pnotepad)
    {
        HWND hwnd;
        hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, pnotepad);
        if (hwnd != 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Now on a checkbox, I want it to check if the process is running.

```
private: System::Void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

if (bool application::GUI::isRunning)
    label1->Text = "cat";
```

I get this error:

> a pointer-to-member is not valid for a managed class

I tried changing it to `&isRunning`. This gives me the same error as above and

> illegal operation on bound member function expression

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

everything with below seems wrong:

```
if (bool application::GUI::isRunning)
```

1. you don't need `bool` if you don't wanna save the result of function. Either define a variable that's bool and assign the result of function to that:

   ```
   bool result = isRunning(...);
   if(result)
        ...
   ```

or

```
if(isRunning())
   ...
```

2. `application::gui::isRunning` expression  returns the pointer of `isRunning` function which you are trying to define as a bool variable.
3. Lets say you fixed first two as:

   ```
   LPCSTR arg = ...;
   if(application::GUI::isRunning(arg))
        label1->Text = "cat";
   ```

Which implies that you are calling `static` function of a `GUI` class
or a function under the namespace of `GUI` (also `GUI` is under `application` namespace).

My guess is `GUI` is a `Form` class so you are trying to invoke and since the function is not `static` you will get error again. So you have two cases to fix:

if you are getting this error from another function of `GUI`

```
 LPCSTR arg = ...;
 if (isRunning(arg))
     label1->Text = "cat";
```

otherwse you need a pointer to GUI object:

```
 LPCSTR arg = ...;
 if (gui-> isRunning(arg))
     label1->Text = "cat";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, GUI is a form. For some reason, I still get the error "A pointer-to-member is not valid for a managed class" from `LPCSTR arg = isRunning;`. `if (GUI->isRunning(arg))` also gives me the error "expression must have bool type (or be convertible to bool)" I'm trying to learn C++ so maybe I'm missing something really easy here.

Comment: @Evan if you are calling the function from somewhere which is another function of GUI just use the first option. Otherwise(lets say you are calling it from GUI2 class) you need a pointer to GUI. I wrote `gui->isRunning()` lower case on purpose. It was supposed to tell you that `gui` is a pointer to instance of GUI. (`GUI *gui = ...`)

Comment: By the way if you are trying to learn c++ you should start from standard c++ (which is currently c++14). `clr` version of c++ is called `visual c++` and it really has differences.

Comment: Still kept getting the error "A pointer-to-member is not valid for a managed class" but I figured it out myself like this. `if (const char LPCSTR = true)
  label1->Text = "running";
 else
  label1->Text = "not running";` I appreciate the help, and thanks for the advice, I'll try to learn regular c++ first. I just wanted a GUI for the small project I'm doing and read QT is hard, didn't know it would be a different variation of c++.

Comment: This also works (I guess it's better since using LPCSTR isn't specific?) `if (const char pnotepad = true) label1->Text = "running"; else label1->Text = "not running";`

Comment: Believe me you haven't figured it out ;) But you should stop here and start from the beginning. Visual studio is a good tool, maybe too much for beginning but it really is good. You can start a regular project by "windows console application" (select empty project). GUI is not standard c++ in any platform.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making function call in incorrect manner.
Probably it should be like below,

```
if (application::GUI::isRunning())
{
    label1->Text = "cat";
}
```

Above is just a hint to make proper function call - but since `isRunning` is a private member function, how it can be invoked directly from outside class and that too without creating any object. It is not a static member function. Please check this point.